# Tableau desktop Azure analysis service tabular role not working

Tags: tableau-api, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

In my analysis service tabular project i have very simple two tables: sales_monthly (fact) and a V_DM_CUST_MASTER (dimension)

[image]

And in role defination:

[image]

[image]

So I put a static row filter to get only rows where province_code="130000" for V_DM_CUST_MASTER
Also I put an user in member section. This user is not AD user. so i added it in 'Add External user'.

In my tableau  server, i have set up an same named user and used that user to log on tableau server. This user is not an windows AD user.
The report shows all the data. It should show sales for province_code = 130000 only. I was tring to set up a dynamic row filter using USERNAME() and LOOKUPVALUE functions but couldn't get it to work, so I created this test demo with only static filer, but it's still not working.

[image]

Comment: First step is to add a measure to return the value of USERNAME() to see the identity of the connected user.

Comment: Yes I have done that and can see in Tableau the USERNAME() actually returns the user added in the role.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the accout I used for the testing is the Azure Analysis Service Admin, so it will not be confined by the Role settings.